# Get value from hidden field by clicking different button

Tags: php

I have different products and it should have a view description that when clicked, a modal will popup and will show descriptions designated to it. But, I tried first getting the value of the hidden field to test it out. It shows the value of the hidden field when I clicked the first button but when I clicked the others, it didn't change. For example: 
Button 1 (View Description): 
Button 2 (View Description): 
When I clicked button 1 it will show in the modal the value of the hidden field which is 1. But when I click the button 2 it will show in the modal 1 again. What should I do to get the value of the hidden field by clicking the button? Here is my code:

```
<div id="display">
             <?php


                include('database_connection.php');

                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id DESC";

                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

                if($statement->execute())
                {
                    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                    $output = '';
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                        $output .= '
                        <form method="post">
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:12px;">  
                            <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; height: 383px;" align="center">
                                <img src="images/'.$row["image"].'" class="img-responsive" /><br />
                                <h4 class="text-info">'.$row["name"].'</h4>
                                <h4 class="text-danger">$ '.$row["price"] .'</h4>
                                <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity' . $row["id"] .'" class="form-control" value="1" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row["name"].'" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row["price"].'" />
                                <input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id="'.$row["id"].'" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success form-control add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="getprod" id="getprod" value="'.$row["id"].'"/>
                                <input type="button" name="description" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success form-control description" value="View Description" />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        ';
                    }
                    echo $output;
                }


                ?>

        </div>


<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

               <?php $prod = $_POST["getprod"]; ?>

                <h1><?php echo $prod; ?></h1>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: are you somehow doing this without javascript?

Comment: @RamRaider yes.

Comment: Code seems fine to me, can you inspect the html and check if the hidden values all got correct values?

Comment: @JensV It all got correct values that's why I don't get it why it only shows the hidden value of button 1

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_POST)` and check the values?

Comment: @JensV It shows the same thing when I clicked the three buttons. array(5) { ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["hidden_name"]=> string(18) "Panasonic T44 Lite" ["hidden_price"]=> string(6) "125.00" ["getprod"]=> string(1) "3" ["description"]=> string(16) "View Description" }

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is if you nested some <form> tags or messed up the html. Can you check in the web inspector if there are any forms in forms? You can also try to put the rendered html through the w3c validator and check for any html errors.